# dotnet core 3 not reading X-FORWARDED-HOST on IIS

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a new dotnet core MVC application that is behind a ARR IIS proxy that isn't reading the X-FORWARDED-HOST header.

Specifically I need the host set correctly as I'm using openID Connect and it needs to write correct redirect URLs.

It works on my VS dev server but not on my staging server.

Now all code uses example.com to replace my real domain.

startup.cs

```cs
var forwardingOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
{
     ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All,
     AllowedHosts = new List<string> { "*.example.com"},
     RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
};
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardingOptions);
```

controller:

```cs
var ret = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
{
    ret.AppendLine(header.Key + ":" + header.Value);
}
return Content(Request.Host  + "\r\n"+ret.ToString());
```

output test (edited to remove not related headers)

```
pc023835.example.com
Host:pc023835.example.com
X-Original-Host:localhost:53848
X-FORWARDED-PORT:443
```

Staging IIS:

```
web-test.example.com
Host:web-test.example.com
X-FORWARDED-HOST:newdev.example.com
X-FORWARDED-PORT:443
X-FORWARDED-PROTO:https
X-Original-URL:/file-downloader/
X-Forwarded-For:10.101.40.1:10400
X-ARR-SSL: EDITED OUT
X-ARR-LOG-ID:d2224167-c14f-43e0-af40-86bfd360d22f
```

Rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^file-downloader/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://web-test.example.com/file-downloader/{R:1}" />
      <serverVariables>
          <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
          <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT" value="443" />
          <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
      </serverVariables>
</rule>
```